# can't see SKEffectNode as a child with suggested effects

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, xcode7-beta6

I'm trying to adjust some effects but I need to use SKEffectNode(), so I wrote the following code:

```
let rocketPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Rocket", ofType: "sks")!
    let rocketFireEmitter = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(rocketPath) as! SKEmitterNode

    //playerNode.addChild(rocketFireEmitter)  // #1

    let firePathEffectMode = SKEffectNode()
    firePathEffectMode.shouldEnableEffects = true
    firePathEffectMode.addChild(rocketFireEmitter)

    playerNode.addChild(firePathEffectMode)   // #2
```

If I use the code identified as #1 - which I commented out - everything works just fine.
But I need to use some effects, so I wrote instead the code block between #1 and #2. I can't see my rocket fire but neither do I receive any error.

I can't find the problem; I tried changing zPosition but to no avail.

I'm using Xcode 7 beta 6.
Thanks guys!

Comment: I think the answer below should be marked as unanswered. I am still having this exact same issue with iOS 9 GM, Xcode 7 GM and swift 2. Are you still having this issue?

Comment: Yes I have the same issue

Comment: Yeah any luck fixing it. I guess I have to remove the SKEffects Node and try to do something else. So annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted a bug report to Apple about this bug.

They're saying the latest version of the beta version of El Capitan fixes the issue for the iOS Simulator. However, I don't recommend beta versions of Mac OS X right now.

The work around is to run this on your iPhone, not the iOS Simulator. It should work on a real device.

> Follow-Up: Bug ID 21509174: SKEffectNode doesn't render on the iOS
>   Simulator for Xcode 7 and Swift 2
>
> We believe this issue has been addressed in the latest OS X El Capitan
>   10.11 update (build 15A263e). This is a pre-release OS X update. Please refer to the release notes for complete installation
>   instructions.
>
> OS X Yosemite 10.11 - Developer beta
>   https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/index.action

Comment: There may be a workaround of adding another SKNode or SKSpriteNode to the SKEffectNode children. I haven't tried it yet, but someone emailed me about it.